# CMD issue in Android Studio and Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I had run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in the CMD and it shows `y/n`. But before clicking `y` it automatically goes back to the command prompt like `c:\users\asus>`. Any suggestions except reset are appreciated

Comment: Please run `flutter doctor` command to see android licences status. Maybe you accepted all licences successfully. But if you did there must be message about that something like : 5 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. If problem continues please share result of `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: No it not accepted it says Android licence status unknown and I tried with powershell,CMD and even in Android studio but I can't type y it's just returns to start

Answer (score 0):

Install the sdk command line tool from Android Studio.

[image]

Run: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Then you should get:

````dart
0 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...             
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? y
...and then you'll get a whole bunch of licenses to read whilst you sip your favourite beverage.```
````